# MySQL SUM values from 2 tables and JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and both `table2` and `table3` may contain an amount for the `key` from table1.

I would like to sum up these values and represent them as `amount`.

```
SELECT table1.mg_key
     , table1.mg_name
     , table1.time
     , table2.mg_amount + table3.mg_amount amount
     , table2.mg_key + table.mg_key
  FROM table
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2
     , table3 
    ON table1.mg_key = key 
   AND key = amount
```

It doesn't work, so Im probably doing something wrong?

Comment: Go read the [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) syntax, then take a close look at what you're doing (wrong).

Comment: do you mean `from table1` .... just don't do joins this way this is so 1996

Comment: @Drew Yes `table1`. Well I found a tutorial that had it done this way...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Drew doesn't really help. I'm very much a newb with all this...

Comment: This would result in a syntax error (for at least two reasons), so I've really no idea what you want from us.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65dca/1/0

```
SELECT   
table1.mg_key, table1.mg_name, table1.time,
IFNULL(table2.mg_amount,0) + IFNULL(table3.mg_amount,0) as amount
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.mg_key = table2.mg_key
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.mg_key = table3.mg_key;
```

If this does not answer your question, please create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to help us better understand.

Comment: It works this way. I've just added `IFNULL(table2.mg_amount,0) + IFNULL(table3.mg_amount,0) as amount` because it didn't display anything when the value was 0. Is this a good/reliable way of doing it?

Comment: @Borsn Yes. I've added this into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use 'key', 'time' as these are reserved words. Sharing your table schemas or creating a fiddle would help.

```
SELECT 
table1.mg_key, table1.mg_name, table1.time,--time= pick other name
IFNULL(table2.mg_amount,0) + IFNULL(table3.mg_amount,0) as amount,
IFNULL(table2.mg_key,0) + IFNULL(table1.mg_key,0) as pkey
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.mg_key = key --key= reserved; pick other name
LEFT JOIN table3 
ON key = amount --key= reserved; pick other name
```

Comment: @Andrew I've picked a new name for key. But it doesn't work.