# sum over values by month from two table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to sum over values by month from two table?

I have two table:

```
1)costs_1

-id
-total
-updated_at(timestamp)

2)costs_2

-id
-total_1
-updated_at_1(timestamp)
```

The result table need have next columns:

```
-total
-total_1
-month
```

For example, if I have one table I do next query:

```
SELECT SUM(total), MONTH(updated_at), YEAR(updated_at) FROM product_sale GROUP BY MONTH(updated_at), YEAR(updated_at) ORDER by MONTH(updated_at)
```

Comment: Can you please post some example data how you want data?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963679/mysql-sum-values-from-2-tables-and-join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SUM values from 2 tables and JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963679/mysql-sum-values-from-2-tables-and-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this.

```
SELECT t1.y year,
       t1.m month,
       t1.total,
       t2.total
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(updated_at) y, 
           MONTH(updated_at) m, 
           SUM(total) total
    FROM costs_1
    GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at), MONTH(updated_at) 
) t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(updated_at_1) y, 
           MONTH(updated_at_1) m, 
           SUM(total_1) total
    FROM costs_2
    GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at_1), MONTH(updated_at_1) 
) t2 ON t1.y = t2.y and t1.m = t2.m
```

However, in this solution, you will miss a month if `costs_1` or `costs_2` does not have any record with the month. If you want FULL JOIN you have to emulate it in mysql using two OUTER JOINS like this:

```
SELECT t1.y year,
       t1.m month,
       COALESCE(t1.total, 0),
       COALESCE(t2.total, 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(updated_at) y, 
           MONTH(updated_at) m, 
           SUM(total) total
    FROM costs_1
    GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at), MONTH(updated_at) 
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(updated_at_1) y, 
           MONTH(updated_at_1) m, 
           SUM(total_1) total
    FROM costs_2
    GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at_1), MONTH(updated_at_1) 
) t2 ON t1.y = t2.y and t1.m = t2.m

   UNION

SELECT t2.y year,
       t2.m month,
       COALESCE(t1.total, 0),
       COALESCE(t2.total, 0)
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(updated_at) y, 
           MONTH(updated_at) m, 
           SUM(total) total
    FROM costs_1
    GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at), MONTH(updated_at) 
) t1
RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(updated_at_1) y, 
           MONTH(updated_at_1) m, 
           SUM(total_1) total
    FROM costs_2
    GROUP BY YEAR(updated_at_1), MONTH(updated_at_1) 
) t2 ON t1.y = t2.y and t1.m = t2.m
```

Comment: you are wellcome :)

Comment: I found bug in this solution: this work only if cost_1, cost_2 both have value of total in some month, if value by some month doesn't exist,for example, exisit  in cost_1 but doesn't exist in cost_2, this month doesn't output but I would like just see 0 in cost_2. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: yes I wrote it my comment bellow solution, there is a fix for this, I will add it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT total, total_1, MONTHNAME(costs_1.updated_at) from costs_1 INNER JOIN costs_2 
ON 
MONTH(costs_1.updated_at)=MONTH(costs_2.updated_at)
```

Comment: In this solution some error: #1052 - Column 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous